# How do re-entrant locks work in this piece of Java code?

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrantlock

I have three classes one is main class, one is a shared resource class and other is thread class. I am facing issue in understanding the code. How can I understand this code, and how can I analyse the code for future reference? `PrintingJob` is a Thread and `PrinterQueue` is the shared resource. I want to see the importance of passing object.

**Class 1**

```
    package com.lock.demo;
    //creating a Thread by implementing the Runnable interface
    class PrintingJob implements Runnable
    {
       private PrinterQueue printerQueue;
       public PrintingJob(PrinterQueue printerQueue)
       {
          this.printerQueue = printerQueue;
       }

       @Override
       public void run()
       {
          System.out.printf("%s: Going to print a document\n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
          printerQueue.printJob(new Object());
       }
    }
```

**class 2**

```
    package com.lock.demo;
    //acts as a shared resource
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
    class PrinterQueue
    {
       private final Lock queueLock = new ReentrantLock();
       public void printJob(Object document)
       {
           //Lock aquired
          queueLock.lock();
          //critical section
          try
          {
             Long duration = (long) (Math.random() * 10000);
             System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": PrintQueue: Printing a Job during " + (duration / 1000) + " seconds :: Time - " + new Date());
             Thread.sleep(duration);
          } catch (InterruptedException e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } finally
          {
             System.out.printf("%s: The document has been printed\n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
             //Lock Released
             queueLock.unlock();
          }
       }
    }
```

**class 3**

```
    package com.lock.demo;
    //main class
    public class LockExample
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          PrinterQueue printerQueue = new PrinterQueue();
          Thread thread[] = new Thread[10];
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          {
             thread[i] = new Thread(new PrintingJob(printerQueue), "Thread " + i);
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          {
             thread[i].start();
          }
       }
    }
```

**My Question:**
From the class 3 in the line -

```
thread[i] = new Thread(new  PrintingJob(printerQueue), "Thread " + i);
```

1. why we are passing printerqueue as an argument here.
2. why we are creating object of PrintingJob

Comment: 1. What do you really expect to be passed as an argument. The constructor expects it. 2. Runnable object is expected in Thread constructor https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html. Is there any problem you are facing with the code?

Answer (score 0):

> why we are passing printerqueue as an argument here.

Your initial description says about which is Thread and which is shared resource.  So when the actual work has to be done you are providing the dependency for the thread which is your shared resource **"printerqueue"**

As you see the code snippet the shared object is initialized only once and in essence shared with the 10 threads you are about to create, simulating 10 different folks/job has initiated printing on that **Printer**

In summary, you have provided 1 "Printer" to 10 Print Jobs.

> why we are creating object of PrintingJob

By Creating the object of **PrintingJob** we are simulating the printing process carried out by the Threads.

Technically you are creating a **Thread** by passing an instance of class implementing **Runnable** interface.